# Type pool or class of constants?

Tags: abap

What is the difference between Type-pool and creating a class for constants?
What is better? 
My question is for a large group of constants and to be accessible to other groups.

Thank you

EDIT - Thank you for the answers and I will improve my question. I need something to store constants and I will use them on programs or other classes. Basically, I wanted to know if it is better to use a type-pool or a class with constants (only). I can have more than one class or type-pool.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptype-pool.htm)? "type groups are obsolete and should no longer be created"

Comment: @petul more than a comment, it's a good answer

Comment: @petul yes I did that first, but my question was beyond from what is in the documentation. This was presented to me at work because a senior told that type-pools can do somethings that classes with constants don't and those things were useful. So they told me to search for it, I tried before coming here. Sorry if I didn't made the question very well.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptype-pool.htm) mentions this:

> Since it is possible to also define data types and constants in the public visibility section of global classes, type groups are obsolete and should no longer be created. Existing type groups can still be used.

A sensibly named interface with the constants you desire is the way to go. An additional benefit is that ABAP OO enforces some more rules.

Comment: Is there any case that type-pools would be better than classes for constants? Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @petul's answer, except for one detail: I'd recommend creating one enumeration-like **class** per logical group of constants, instead of collecting constants in interfaces.

Consider using the new `enum` language feature for specifying the constant values.

Interfaces can be accidentally "implemented", which doesn't make sense here. Classes can prevent this with `final`.

Making one class per logical group simplifies finding the constants with IDE features such as Ctrl+Shift+A search in the ABAP Development Tools. Constants that are randomly thrown together into interfaces are hard to find later on.

Classes allow adding enumeration-like helper methods like converters, existence checks, numbering all values.

Classes also allow adding unit tests, such as ensuring that the constant collection is still in sync with the fixed values of an underlying domain.

Comment: AFAIK, `enum` is valid only for CDS annotations, no?

Comment: No, `enum` is a relatively new ABAP feature that came with NW 7.51. Horst Keller's blog nicely summarizes its usage in https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/10/abap-news-release-7.51-enumerations/. The gist is that you can now type `TYPES: BEGIN OF ENUM tshirt_size, s, m, l, xl, END OF ENUM tshirt_size.` to get a type-safe list of possible values. However, we so far found its usage limited as it does not extend to the database layer.